# Cart Rule Minimum Order from Category with quantity multiples

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

In my the store there is a category for wines. Customers can choose from any of the wines in this category but should only be able to proceed to checkout with a case quantity of bottles (i.e 6 bottles / 12 bottles ..and so on).

I read somewhere that Magento cannot offer this functionality but want to check here or will I need an extension to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

i tried following with Magento 1.9.0.1 and the sample Data and it worked fine for simple products.

In the Adminpanel go to Catalog -> Manage Products and choose a product to edit.
Then click on Inventory -> set Enable Qty Increments to yes, and set Qty Increments to for example 3, i also set the Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart to 3 -> save and refresh cache.
See my Screenshot for the settings:

[image]

Hope my answer helped you solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks but this is at product level, I'm looking for something to control at category level - a minimum quantity of products from a single parent category.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your question. Take a look here: 
[Magento: limit 3 products from category per order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345619/magento-limit-3-products-from-category-per-order)  it´s similar to your problem, maybe it points in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I think the following extension can be good for you:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/limit-order-quantity-per-category.html

As I read, this module allows us to set up minimum and maximum order quantity of each category. Therefore, for your case, you can set up minimum order quantity for the wine category as 6 bottles (or 12 bottles). Customers can choose any number of wine types belonging to this category and they can just checkout when the total quantity is at least 6

Hope it help for you!